# How to a guest can edit .txt file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, text

I'm creating a tool like Pastebin for train myself in PHP (I'm a beginner yet).

Everyone without log in/sign up can create .txt file and share it easily.

Anyway, I'm facing a  problem:

How can a guest edit the .txt file when he created it?

```
<?php 
$titleFile =  $_POST['title']; 
$textFile =  $_POST['text']; 
$newFile = fopen($titleFile . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($newFile, $textFile); 
$url = $titleFile . ".txt";
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

http://mattewdev.altervista.org/

Comment: You will quickly get problems with saving these text files to the file system (colliding names, etc). Any reason why you can't just store the text in a database?

Comment: @JimL I wouldn't know how to do it. I dunno SQL.

Comment: You don't know this either, try both and learn twice as much :D

Comment: Ok, Should I study SQL?

Comment: use a database is definitively the best way to achieve your needs! You will have to go through a lot of pain using files ;) Start looking for `mysql php` you will find a lot of tuto, courses, examples